# TSQL is with error?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
create table Tramite
(
ID int primary key identity(1,1),
IDPersona int foreign key references Persona(ID),
Cantidad nvarchar(20),
Precio int,
NumeroDeControl int,
ReciboDeControl int,
NumeroVisa int,
NumeroVisaRecibido int,
PrecioVisa int,
NumeroVisaAutorizado int
)
```

It says the restriccion isn't valid. Any ideas why?

I am certain I have a table called Persona. I'm running this statement from within Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. Maybe I need to specify something else?

Why wouldn't this run?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ex7Y.png

Comment: Is there a column called ID that is an `int` and is the primary key in the `Persona` table?

Comment: I was able to get your statement to run as is as long as I had a Persona table with a primary key called `ID` in the same database. Are you sure you are trying to execute this against the same database in which the Persona table exists?

Answer (score 1):

```
create table Tramite 
( 
ID int primary key identity(1,1), 
IDPersona int constraint FK_Tramite_Persona foreign key references Persona(ID), 
Cantidad nvarchar(20), 
Precio int, 
NumeroDeControl int, 
ReciboDeControl int, 
NumeroVisa int, 
NumeroVisaRecibido int, 
PrecioVisa int, 
NumeroVisaAutorizado int 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the "foreign key references Persona(ID)" out and just run this after your CREATE TABLE statement.

```
ALTER TABLE [Tramite] WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Tramite_Persona_FK1] FOREIGN KEY([IDPersona]) REFERENCES [Persona] ([ID])

ALTER TABLE [Tramite] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Tramite_Persona_FK1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need "foreign key references", only "references", but I'm not sure if that is causing your issue. The examples on msdn only use "references", you can see that [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Like Thomas said in his comment on your question, your statement works if a `Persona` table exists, and has a primary or candidate key that can be referenced by the foreign key constraint.

The following statements work in my environment (SQL Server 2008 R2).

```
create table Persona (ID int not null primary key)
go
create table Tramite
(
  ID int primary key identity(1,1),
  IDPersona int foreign key references Persona(ID),
  Cantidad nvarchar(20),
  Precio int,
  NumeroDeControl int,
  ReciboDeControl int,
  NumeroVisa int,
  NumeroVisaRecibido int,
  PrecioVisa int,
  NumeroVisaAutorizado int
)
go
```

Perhaps you should try creating a mock Persona table as a test.  If it succeeds, and you believe this table should already exist, then perhaps you created the Persona table under a different schema. I didn't see any schema names assigned to the tables in your screen shot.